# Sqlalchemy parse of joined field

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

This is the example from the documentation:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel, HttpUrl

app = FastAPI()


class Image(BaseModel):
    url: HttpUrl
    name: str


class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    description: str | None = None
    price: float
    tax: float | None = None
    tags: set[str] = set()
    image: Image | None = None
```

In my case, I want only to have an image id or any other field since the Image can be a huge object something like:

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    description: str | None = None
    price: float
    tax: float | None = None
    tags: set[str] = set()
    image_id: Image.id
```

is there a way to do it with pydantic only wihtout extra parsing with python?

Comment: Pydantic's models do not describe relationships, but their types. You have to type hint `image_id` with `int` type and describe relationships inside sqlalchemy's `declarative_base` models

Comment: can you write an example or link to the documentation?